# How to embed skydrive survey in a website?

Tags: html, iframe, onedrive

I need to embed skydrive excel survey in my web site.
Skydrive doesn't support generating html to embedding in website today.

Iframe can be used, but it redirects the page to skydrive.

Link to the survey http://sdrv.ms/1fUtCWB

Answer (score 0):

According to the [one member of MS Excel Web App Team](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeonline-excel_online/embed-a-survey-into-a-pageblog/20b061b2-8ea8-438c-82c5-c03b0f5eb233) it is not possible at the moment.  I personaly expect this feature to come soon, since their direct competitor (Google Docs) allows this. But what does "soon" mean for people in Redmond I don't know...